# How do I draw transparent Rectangles using DirectX in C++?

Tags: c++, graphics, draw, msdn

I want to draw objects to be partially transparent, but I don't know how.
I'm using MSDN and coding in C++.

The following code is how I draw a regular rectangle, but I want to draw a transparent rectangle.

```
VOID DrawingObject::Draw()
{
    ID2D1HwndRenderTarget *m_pRenderTarget;
    m_pRenderTarget->FillRectangle(RectF(10, 10, 20, 20),
        m_pD2DDriver->GetBrush(static_cast<DrawingColor>(m_uColorIndex))
        );
}
```

Any help or guidance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Think you meant **DirectX API**, not MSDN (which is a developer resource library system for Windows program engineers).

Comment: Good call! I was confused.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at the [Brush Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd371173%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  You can create a brush and use `SetOpacity` to create a transparent brush to send to the rectangle.

You can also just create the color directly with the `D2D1::ColorF(red,green,blue,alpha)` function.  The `alpha` argument is transparency.  `0` is completely transparent while `1` is opaque.

If you are unaware on how to use it, [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd756651%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) contains fantastic examples with code on how to use the **ID2D1 Brushes**.  Below is some sample code from that page.

```
ID2D1SolidColorBrush *pGridBrush = NULL;
hr = pCompatibleRenderTarget->CreateSolidColorBrush(
    D2D1::ColorF(D2D1::ColorF(0.93f, 0.94f, 0.96f, 1.0f)),
    &pGridBrush
    );
```

Comment: Thanks Kirk, this is exactly what I was looking for. Appreciate it (: